# What happens in a multi-party webrtc connection when some users use STUN and/or TURN?

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn, signalmaster

In my case, I have a webrct based web app that supports multi-parti video chat and has STUN and TURN servers configured. The connections are done in a mesh way (peer to peer) What happens when some of the users involved in the video chat need to establish the connection via TURN? Do all of the users start to use TURN? What if I'm the user that's behind a NAT? Does that mean that all connections established with me are using TURN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connections are peer to peer, so if one connection uses TURN then it doesn't affect other peer to peer connections.

If the user is behind a NAT, he may not need TURN in some cases: all depends on the type of the NAT.

Comment: Just a follow up question, what happens during a video call if your TURN server has a low bandwidth? Does the entire room go down or just the users connected with TURN?

Comment: @ee11131, there is no notion of rooms in peer to peer. So it's up to the implementation of your application to decide what the room is and what happens with it.

Comment: It's no different than if a pair of peers directly connected without TURN had a direct p2p connection, but with limited bandwith between each other.  The codec adjusts to encode a lower bitrate (and hence, lower quality) video stream.

Comment: If you are aiming to build a large mesh of over 4 browsers, then just don't - it is highly complicated to do that right, and close to impossible if you want any decent quality to come out of it.